# Remove link for Woocommerce product tags

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tags

Is there a way to list the tags for a WooCommerce product without the link behind them?

I have the following code for adding tags to the shop page, but I would like to have the tags listed without hyperlinks.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 5 );

function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
global $post, $product;

$tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );

echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<p>' . _n( '', '', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '</p>' );
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to take the link tag out?

Comment: To hide the fact that it's a tag.

Comment: You could use the method [get_tag_ids](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) to get an array of tag ids. And then you can use the wordpress function [get_tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag) to get the name of every tag. By the way the method [get_tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product.html) is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Another way is to display: none the tags in css; each tag should come with a generic "tag" class, or similar.